# Dask distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker issue

Tags: python-3.x, dask-distributed

I am using Dask and a bit confused.

I run the below and just get this, until the process crashes.

It uses 100% of all 4 CPU cores while its failing;

Can anyone advise me?

```
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
```

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import time
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
%time dahsn = dd.read_csv("US_Accidents_Dec19.csv")
dahsn.groupby('City').count().compute()
```

Comment: Could you share your csv file?

Comment: I get the same error when I try to pass in pandas dataframes

Comment: I have the same error. Can you share the solution?